# React Native Expo How to Hide Status and bar make component take that place

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am not able to fill the status bar area with component. I tried to do it by hiding the status bar using `<StatusBar hidden />`. But this one leaves a white space there. For example I want to fill the green image the status bar.
[image: Here I want to remove the white color of status bar]

Comment: hi, I am unable to recreate this issue, can you please provide a GitHub link with sample code?

Comment: Hi, @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN Actually I have made the app too complicated. I will properly format it will paste the git link. As of now the basic boilerplate code - [link](https://gist.github.com/rushmedev/25f8f231c5ef42261c750bc7022d5625) . I just want to fill the background to full screen even under the status bar.

Comment: found the solution, give me some moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: working project [link](https://github.com/mrpmohiburrahman/whiteStatusBar)

On the gist [link](https://gist.github.com/rushmedev/25f8f231c5ef42261c750bc7022d5625) (you've provided on the comment), I can see that you are using the following structure

```
<SafeAreaView>
      <StatusBar ... />
      <ImageBackground ...></ImageBackground>
 </SafeAreaView>
```

If you want to hide the status bar and cover the whole screen with the image you need to change `SafeAreaView` to just `View` and also remove `StatusBar` component.

```
<View>
      <ImageBackground ...></ImageBackground>
</View>
```

Cause [SafeAreaView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview) will dynamically put some padding at the top. So although you've put `style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}` it will respect the padding of SafeAreaView cause it is the parent component here.

Also at this point, you do not need `StatusBar`, cause the StatusBas already has an image as background.

Comment: @Rashmi Ranjan Bisoi, check this answer. If it solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: @Rashmi Ranjan Bisoi, Awesome, keep hacking!!!